# Apache Spark ownership Vs Ignite Ownership

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I have been going through Ignite SharedRDD in Spark and would like to understand the underlying execution layers/ phases involved in the Spark-Ignite job.

In the [ScalarSharedRDDExample.scala](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/ignite/scalar/examples/spark/ScalarSharedRDDExample.scala),

- where does the following transformation executes?

***val df = transformedValues.sql("select _val from Integer where _val < 100 and _val > 9 ")***

- How does the spark and ignite divide the ownership of a spark application?

(Who is responsible for what?)

- What are the best practices in building Spark-Ignite applications?

Answer (score 1):

Everything still executes they way it used to be. IgniteRDD is implemented as a view over a distributed Ignite cache, which may be deployed either within the Spark job executing process, or on a Spark worker, or in its own cluster.

As per information on their website, shared state may either exist only during the lifespan of a Spark application (embedded mode), or it may out-survive the Spark application (standalone mode), in which case the state can be shared across multiple Spark.

For more information check official website
[Shared Apache Spark RDDs](https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html)

Also read some of the documented use cases which helps to understand better.

[Distributed Database](https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/database/distributed-database.html)
[Key-Value Store](https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/database/key-value-store.html)

See code example, IgniteContext is created from sparkContext.

```
val igniteContext = new IgniteContext(sparkContext, 
    () => new IgniteConfiguration())
```

Hope this helps ! Cheers !

Comment: Though IgniteRDD is an implementation of AbstractRDD, the SQL plan for that query will be generated by Ignite and not Spark SQL. (reference -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ou2Kxy2PNWU ) I'm wondering how Spark understands the general plan prepared by Ignite???

Comment: I believe Ignite SQL will be executed by Ignite Cache Query. https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#query(org.apache.ignite.cache.query.Query) ..

Comment: I think when we use IgniteRDD it gets information from underlying Spark infrastrucure, thanks for sharing youtube video will see it. Its pretty new even i am still learning :-)

Comment: This note is the closest to understanding of architecture "In addition to all the standard RDD functionality, also shares the state of the RDD across other Spark jobs, applications and workers."

Comment: That's true. But how it does? This is required for application debugging and performance tuning. This is what I am more interested.

Comment: @VijayInnamuri - I just added a small snippet to answer, IgniteContext is created from sparkcontext so it has a reference to build on top of what spark provides.

Answer (score 0):

> where does the following transformation executes?

SQL executed on Ignite nodes.

> How does the spark and ignite divide the ownership of a spark application?

You can read about it [here](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/v2.1/docs/ignite-for-spark)

> What are the best practices in building Spark-Ignite applications?

Ignite can provide shared storage, so the state can be passed from one Spark application or job to another.

Ignite can provide SQL with indexing so Spark SQL can be accelerated over 1,000x (spark doesn’t index the data)

When working with files instead of RDDs, the Apache Ignite In-Memory File System (IGFS) can also share state between Spark jobs and applications.

Well, best practices is a too wide question - I think you need to start with [Ignite Example](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/spark/org/apache/ignite/examples/spark/SharedRDDExample.java) and ask a certain question if you will face any problem.